# Clojure JUNG setVertexFillPaintTransformer

Tags: java, clojure, transform, jung

i have a graph, builded with JUNG.
Now i want to change the color of specific vertex.
In Java that would be something like this:

```
    Transformer<V, Paint> vertexPaintRed = new Transformer<V, Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(V input) {
         return Color.red;
    }
};

vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexColor);
```

When i translate this to Clojure

```
(def vertex-paint (proxy [Transformer] [] (transform [i] java.awt.Color/GREEN)))
(.setVertexFillPaintTransformer vertex-paint)
```

Following Exception is thrown:
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast tableau.tableau.proxy$java.lang.Object$Transformer$4341005c to com.google.common.base.Function`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got it:
I added `[com.google.guava/guava "21.0"]` to my Leiningen dependencies
imported `com.google.common.base.Function`in the specific namespace
and changed

```
(def vertex-paint (proxy [Transformer] [] (transform [i] java.awt.Color/GREEN)))
```

to

```
(def vertex-paint (proxy [Function] [] (apply [i] java.awt.Color/GREEN)))
```

Function and apply comes from com.google.commom.base.Function.